# How to remove white space of radio button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to remove those white spaces of right side of Radio buttons as you can see the screenshot I attached -> [in Layout Inspecter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03RYL.png)

I programmatically added radiobuttons with options that

```
RadioButton.setClickable(false),
RadioButton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.input)
```

into Linearlayout with params with 
options that

```
params.weight = 1,
params.gravitiy = Gravity.CENTER,
params.setMargins(4,0,4,0),
```

It is work with this params in xml [in XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drjH6.png) but it doesn't work if I added Radio button programmatically

This is properties of Radiobutton in Layout Inspector

```
fg_ null
getEllipsize()  null
getFilterTouchesWhenObscured()  false
getFitsSystemWindows()  false
getScrollBarStyle() INSIDE_OVERLAY
getTag()    null
getTransitionName() null
getVisibility() VISIBLE
isActivated()   false
isChecked() false
isClickable()   false
isEnabled() true
isFocusableInTouchMode()    false
isHapticFeedbackEnabled()   true
isHovered() false
isInTouchMode() true
isPressed() false
isSelected()    false
isSoundEffectsEnabled() true
mID NO_ID
mPrivateFlags   0x1008830
mPrivateFlags_DRAWN 0x20
mSystemUiVisibility 0x0
mSystemUiVisibility_SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE  0x0
mViewFlags  0x18000001
getContentDescription() null
getImportantForAccessibility()  yes
getLabelFor()   -1
getAlpha()  1.0
getElevation()  0.0
getPivotX() 154.0
getPivotY() 102.0
getRotation()   0.0
getRotationX()  0.0
getRotationY()  0.0
getScaleX() 1.0
getScaleY() 1.0
getSolidColor() 0
getTransitionAlpha()    1.0
getTranslationX()   0.0
getTranslationY()   0.0
getTranslationZ()   0.0
getX()  320.0
getY()  0.0
getZ()  0.0
hasOverlappingRendering()   true
hasShadow() false
isDrawingCacheEnabled() false
isHardwareAccelerated() true
isOpaque()  false
mLayerType  NONE
willNotCacheDrawing()   false
willNotDraw()   false
hasFocus()  false
isFocusable()   true
isFocused() false
getBaseline()   120
getHeight() 204
getLayoutDirection()    RESOLVED_DIRECTION_LTR
getLocationOnScreen_x() 408
getLocationOnScreen_y() 602
getRawLayoutDirection() INHERIT
getWidth()  308
hasTransientState() false
isLayoutRtl()   false
layout_bottomMargin 0
layout_endMargin    -2147483648
layout_gravity  CENTER
layout_height   WRAP_CONTENT
layout_leftMargin   4
layout_mMarginFlags 0x00
layout_rightMargin  4
layout_startMargin  -2147483648
layout_topMargin    0
layout_weight   1.0
layout_width    WRAP_CONTENT
mBottom 204
mLeft   320
mRight  628
mTop    0
getMeasuredHeightAndState() 204
getMeasuredWidthAndState()  308
mMeasuredHeight 204
mMeasuredWidth  308
mMinHeight  0
mMinWidth   0
mPaddingBottom  0
mPaddingLeft    0
mPaddingRight   0
mPaddingTop 0
mUserPaddingBottom  0
mUserPaddingEnd -2147483648
mUserPaddingLeft    0
mUserPaddingRight   0
mUserPaddingStart   -2147483648
mScrollX    0
mScrollY    0
getRawTextAlignment()   GRAVITY
getRawTextDirection()   INHERIT
getScaledTextSize() 14.117646
getSelectionEnd()   -1
getSelectionStart() -1
getTextAlignment()  GRAVITY
getTextDirection()  FIRST_STRONG
getTextSize()   48.0
getTypefaceStyle()  NORMAL
mCurTextColor   -16777216
mGravity    17
mText   
android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar() forced
    forced
```

Anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For who needs help, just use this method

```
RadioButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.image_name,null),null,null);
```

it removes it's left padding